# Retrieve data from table into another table in Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to retrieve a data from one table in my database and insert into another table, but null is assigned instead of the value. I want to get the name of the current user from the Account table and insert in the Booking table.

```
mDatabase.getReference().child("Accounts").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if(dataSnapshot.exists()){

                Accounts accounts = dataSnapshot.getValue(Accounts.class);
                assert accounts != null;
                Value = accounts.getName();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

Here is the insertion code for the retrieved value from Account table:

```
mDatabase.getReference("Booking").child(mKeys.get(position)).child("name").setValue(Value);
```

here is the part where i'm calling the above statement:

```
        holder.mCardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(mBookList.get(position).getPic().equals("button")&&mBookList.get(position).isAvailability()){
                AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
                builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Picasso.with(mContext).load(R.drawable.unavailablef).into(holder.imageView);
                        mDatabase.getReference("Booking").child(mKeys.get(position)).child("availability").setValue(false).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                Toast.makeText(mContext,"Confirmed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });
                        mDatabase.getReference("Booking").child(mKeys.get(position)).child("userID").setValue(mUser.getUid());
                        information();
                        mDatabase.getReference("Booking").child(mKeys.get(position)).child("name").setValue(Value);
```

and this is what i get when i run the code with a debug:

[image]

Comment: how you are calling 'mDatabase.getReference("Booking").child(mKeys.get(position)).child("name").setValue(Value);'

Comment: In which part of your code are you using `mDatabase.getReference("Booking").child(mKeys.get(position)).child("name").setValue(Value);`? Please also respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: I have added the part of the code in which i'm calling the above statement in, please take a look and i'm waiting for your reply..

Comment: I have added the part of the code in which i'm calling the above statement in, please take a look and i'm waiting for your reply..